# "Magical" identity between primitives.

Tags: calculus, education

Well, we mathematicians know that (given some "usual" hypotheses) $f'(x)=g'(x)\implies f(x)-g(x)=C$, where $C$ is a constant.

My question is about an elementary example in this context which should be *surprising*. $\arcsin$ and the like is too difficult for my pupils. Is there anything simpler? The point is to show that, given two functions, if their derivative is the same, these functions are necessarily the same, up to a constant.

Comment: $f(x) = -\sin^2 x, g(x) = \cos^2 x, h(x) = \frac 12 \cos 2x$

Comment: That0s a good example, but my pupils don't know about this kind of trogonmetical identities

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(-x+\pi/2),g(x)=\cos(-x)+\pi/2$

Comment: Note that examples like those by @DougM are actual practical examples that trip up students in integration exercises. e.g. you see questions like  "Help! I get $-\sin^2(x) + C$ as the antiderivative, but the answer key says $\cos^2(x) + C$."

Comment: These usually start popping up quite naturally once you get to the calculus of trigonometric functions, as there are multiple ways to represent the same function, and students have more flexibility choose their integration techniques.  If you have only covered polynomials and their relatives, then the examples are going to be more obvious.  I remember it being a small surprise to realize $\ln (\frac 12 x + 1)  + C= \ln (x + 2)$  But if you haven't covered trig, have you covered logs?

Comment: Aside: while you're covering counterexamples like this, it might be useful to demonstrate functions that *don't* differ by a constant, but have the same derivative. For example, antiderivatives of $1/x$ on the nonzero reals may fail to differ by a constant (but they do always differ by something that is *locally* constant). Alas, I don't know of any natural-looking example; everything that comes to mind is piecewise defined.

Comment: @DougM But... in order to convince pupils that $-\sin^2x$, $\cos^2 x$ and $.5\cos 2x$ differ by constants, you have to prove that
$$-2\sin x \cos x = -\sin 2x,$$
which, depending on the intent (show that $\cos^2 x - .5\cos 2x = \cos^2 0 - .5\cos 0 = .5$ vs. warn pupils about apparently different results), might be equally difficult.

Comment: @peterwhy I would say that if you don't know that $\cos 2x  = 2\cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$ you are not ready for calculus.  You are going to need to apply that very identity repeatedly.

Comment: Doesn't exactly fit as an answer to the question as asked - but I like this example using a similar principle: $y = \sin(x+a)$ satisfies the differential equation $y''=y$, therefore it's a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and by considering $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ you can derive the formula $\sin(x+a) = \cos a \sin x + \sin a \cos x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(2x)$?

There's not much to this except contriving a pair of formulas which look deceptively different.

Comment: Oh, yes. Simple enough.

Comment: Stupid example:  $f(x) = x^2 + \sqrt{\pi} - e^{\sqrt{79}}/\cos \pi^{9}$; $g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That kind of example is useful to show that  some letters can be as constant as $3$...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

(a) Derive a formula for the derivative of $h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$.

(b) Use the formula to compute the derivative of $h(x)=x^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$.

(c) Explain the result.